# IE6 footer layout breaking

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

can someone spot why this layout is breaking in IE6? have tried various options but still the same. please see screen shots for exact problem. thanks

Screen Shots

http://img232.imageshack.us/i/footerie6.png/

http://img546.imageshack.us/i/footerie7.png/

HTML

```
<div id="footer">
      <div class="footerLogos">

        <img src="images/psw.png" alt="Footer Divider" width="164" height="50" />
        <br /><br /><br />
        <div class="footerLogosText">
          Pocket Size Websites
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="containerFooterBlock">
      <div class="footerTextabout">
            Quick Links<br />

              <br />
        <div class="footerTextContent">
          <ul>

            <li><a href="#">Unique Website Design & Development</a></li>
            <li>E-Commerce Shopping Carts</li>
            <li>Content Management Systems (CMS)</li>
            <li>Search Engine Optimization (SEO)</li>
            <li>Logo &amp; Brochure Design</li>
          </ul>

        </div>
            <img src="images/footer-div.png" alt="Footer Divider" width="2" height="256" />
      </div>


      <div class="footerTextabout">
            Resources<br />

              <br />
        <div class="footerTextContent">
              <ul>
             <li>Unique Website Design & Development</li>


            <li>E-Commerce Shopping Carts</li>


            <li>Content Management Systems (CMS)</li>


            <li>Search Engine Optimization (SEO)</li>


            <li>Web Hosting</li>


            <li>Logo &amp; Brochure Design</li>

          </ul>

          </div>

                  <img src="images/footer-div.png" alt="Footer Divider" width="2" height="256" />
      </div>
      <div class="footerTextabout">
            Blogs<br />

              <br />
          <div class="footerTextContent">
              <ul>
             <li>Unique Website Design & Development</li>


            <li>E-Commerce Shopping Carts</li>


            <li>Content Management Systems (CMS)</li>


            <li>Search Engine Optimization (SEO)</li>


            <li>Web Hosting</li>


            <li>Logo &amp; Brochure Design</li>

          </ul>

          </div>
                <!--<img src="images/footer-div.png" alt="Footer Divider" width="2" height="256" />-->

      </div>
      </div>
      <div id="footerText">
        &copy; some domain 2011
      </div>

  </div>
```

CSS

```
#footer
    {

            width: 999px;
            height:500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-image: url(../images/footer-bg.png);
            background-position: center center;
            background-repeat: repeat-x;

    }

#footerText
    {

            text-align: center;
            padding: 38px 0 0 0;
            font: 11px Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            color: #000;

    }

.containerFooterBlock
    {

            float:left;
            width: 999px;
            padding: 3px 0 0 0;
            clear:both;

    }

.footerTextabout
    {

            width:280px;
            height:300px;
            float:left;
            font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 20px;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: normal;
            padding: 20px 0 0 36px;
            clear:none;

    }

.footerTextContent
    {

            width:250px;
            height:400px;
            float:left;
            font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: normal;
            padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
            line-height: 30px;
            text-align:justify;

    }

.footerTextContent li
    {
            padding: 0 0 0 25px;
            list-style-type: none;
            background-image:url(../images/tick.png);
            background-position: left 7px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat



    }

.footerTextabout img
    {

            float:left;
            padding:10px 0 0 18px;

    }

.footerLogos
    {

            width:250px;
            float:left;
            font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #666;
            font-weight: normal;
            padding: 15px 0 0 24px;


    }

.footerLogosText
    {

            width:250px;
            float:left;
            font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 11px;
            color: #999;
            font-weight: normal;
            padding: 2px 0 0 32px;

    }

.footerLogos img
    {

            float:left;
            padding:5px 0 5px 0;
            border: 1px solid black;

    }
            <div class="footerTextContent">
              <ul>

                <li><a href="#">Unique Website Design & Development</a></li>
                <li>E-Commerce Shopping Carts</li>
                <li>Content Management Systems (CMS)</li>
                <li>Search Engine Optimization (SEO)</li>
                <li>Logo &amp; Brochure Design</li>
              </ul>

            </div>
                <img src="images/footer-div.png" alt="Footer Divider" width="2" height="256" />
          </div>


          <div class="footerTextabout">
                Resources<br />

                  <br />
            <div class="footerTextContent">
                  <ul>
                 <li>Unique Website Design & Development</li>


                <li>E-Commerce Shopping Carts</li>


                <li>Content Management Systems (CMS)</li>


                <li>Search Engine Optimization (SEO)</li>


                <li>Web Hosting</li>


                <li>Logo &amp; Brochure Design</li>

              </ul>

              </div>

                      <img src="images/footer-div.png" alt="Footer Divider" width="2" height="256" />
          </div>
          <div class="footerTextabout">
                Blogs<br />

                  <br />
              <div class="footerTextContent">
                  <ul>
                 <li>Unique Website Design & Development</li>


                <li>E-Commerce Shopping Carts</li>


                <li>Content Management Systems (CMS)</li>


                <li>Search Engine Optimization (SEO)</li>


                <li>Web Hosting</li>


                <li>Logo &amp; Brochure Design</li>

              </ul>

              </div>
                    <!--<img src="images/footer-div.png" alt="Footer Divider" width="2" height="256" />-->

          </div>
          </div>
          <div id="footerText">
            &copy; some domain 2011
          </div>

      </div>
```

Comment: I think its because its IE 6. Hate that version! :P

Comment: If I may be so bold: IE6 is dead and buried. Don't think about it, don't worry about it, don't pander to it. It's over. It's gone. We can breathe easy.

Comment: Although apparently a lot of China still uses it. Still, their loss.

Comment: @ it may have only 6% of browser share but those 6% are some of the biggest companies trading today. go figure

Comment: I would like to add that 6% means tens of millions of people. You can't simply ignore them entirely. Better user experience for those who use modern browser is always good, but the site needs to be accessible also for users using old browsers.

Comment: well said jose. need to cater for the monority as well as the majority

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.footerLogos {
    width:999px;
}
```

I don't see why that box should be so small since everything else is anyway displayed on its bottom.

Maybe with this you don't need the float anymore.

Comment: @jose sorry i do not understand your comment. the container width is 999px and the footer is 999px?

Comment: Since from what I can see there are no other elements to the right of .footerLogos, probably giving it a width of 999px will let it occupy all the footer width, so that the other content will stick by itself to the bottom, without even the need to make things float.

Comment: @jose i have made the width 999px and removed the float and i have posted the result here: http://img402.imageshack.us/i/footerie6update.png/ no matter what i do i cannot get that footer down. thanks

Comment: That's better than before, now you have the one on top of the other at least. Now you shuold try to play a little with margins/paddings of both .footerLogos and .containerFooterBlock.

Comment: @jose no matter what i do with margins and padding makes no difference. will keep going though :-) anything else springs to mind drop a comment. many thanks

Comment: @jose i think it is the footer that is causing the probs. the footer does not move at all. i shall create a border around it to show the area it occupies.

Comment: did you still mantain the float property to one of the two elements? if so, maybe you need to add also the height of the upper element if you are trying to use a margin-top on the bottom element. So for example you are using margin-top:20px; and the upper element is floating and has a height of 100px you need to use margin-top:120px;

Comment: @jose http://img846.imageshack.us/i/footerie6updated.png/ you will see that the outline of the footer and it is much too high. even if adjust the other divs the footer will still occupy to much space above. needs to move down so the container can expand down.

Comment: There may be also other workarounds, for example the bottom element could have position:absolute, the parent element position:relative; and you only need to specify a top value. Or you can use border-top:xxx px solid transparent; instead of margins

Comment: @jose thanks very much. will dabble with your suggestions and post back here. kudos to you :-)

Comment: just an update. i managed to sort this out by taking the footer div out of the container and styling the div seperately. IE6 did not want to play ball while the footer was in the container. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `clear:both` to the LAST element in the footer: `#footerText`

Answer (score 0):

well assuming you have the two closing divs in your html structure, my guess is that it is a float problem. put this before the closing div for #footer and you should be alright:

```
<div style='clear:both'></div>
```

also add

```
#footer{
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your #footer css:

```
#footer{
    clear:both;
}
```